# File/Blob - eslint(no-undef)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, apollo, next.js

While creating an Apollo Client in a NextJS/TypeScript project, I need to figure out whether the current operation is Upload or not, but ESLint complains that `File` and `Blob` are not defined.

I can disable warning: `// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef` but I’d like to understand why there’s such warning and I’d like to fix it without ignoring if possible.

```
const isFile = (value: any): boolean => {
  if (isPlainObject(value) || Array.isArray(value)) {
    return Object.values(value).map(isFile).includes(true)
  }
  const isfile = typeof File !== 'undefined' && value instanceof File
  const isblob = typeof Blob !== 'undefined' && value instanceof Blob
  return isfile || isblob
}
const isUpload = ({ variables }: any) => {
  return Object.values(variables).some(isFile)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `browser: true` to your ESLint config file inside the `env` prop:

```
// .eslintrc
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  }
}
```